# Server 2012 R2 Hyper-V RAID-1

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012

I am trying to setup the free version of Hyper-V 2012 at my office. This system will replace an existing VM infrastructure that uses VMWare on Linux. The physical machine has 2x 1TB HDDs that I'd like to configure in a RAID-1 mirror to provide some level of safeguard in the case one of the HDDs fails.

In server 2008 this is easily acheived via disk management by converting both disks to dynamic and enabling mirroring. However, in the free Hyper-V I can't get to disk manager (there is no UI), and connecting to the disk management snap in from a remote computer fails.

Thoughts/Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, given that you're using Server 2012 R2, I'd suggest Storage Spaces as your solution.  You can set that up with PowerShell.  On my machine, I just dumped the list of relevant powershell cmdlets with the following command:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> gcm -Module storage
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the command line to achieve the same result.

Below seems to give a pretty good explanation of the commands needed:

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_and_Managing_Windows_Server_2008_Mirrored_%28RAID_1%29_Volumes

(Listed as 2008 instructions but the commands used are all pretty standard, should work the same way)

The instructions for mirrored disks start about 2/3 down the page.

File and storage services should be installed by default, should be able to go ahead and try it out without having to install anything additional.